# Performance implications for using an identity column or a homegrown sequence table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a legacy system that is using a table for sequencing numbers.  The table has the following definition:

```
dbo.id_table
(
    table_name char(64) NOT NULL,
    id_type char(5) NOT NULL,
    data_type char(5) NOT NULL,
    next_id_number int NOT NULL,
    next_id_max char(15) NOT NULL
)
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    table_name ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This table is functionally equivalent for an identity column.

Here is how the table is used:
-A stored procedure runs to get the next value of the id in the table.  e.g.,

```
exec id_proc 'bryans_table', @some_int_value output
```

I am looking for an expert to answer the following question:

What are the performance implications (as specific as possible) for using a design like this with SQL Server 2008 R2 (currently running in compatibility mode, but plans to use full 2008 R2 at some point in the future) vs. using a regular identity column?  Does this scale at all?

We are seeing a lot of contention is this table and I want to know if the tables were switched to identity columns what type of performance gains might be had (or lost)?  At this point the source of contention is unclear.

(I do not know why an identity column was not included in the original design  -- this is a legacy database)

Comment: You also might consider sequences, although they will have identical behavior and performance.

Comment: @usr sequences are new in SQL Server 2012, so unfortunately they won't work in this case

Comment: Also, you should elaborate on why you would want a sequence table anyway. With the current information their only advantage would be guaranteed contiguous IDs.

Comment: @usr: often times client side app code can be simplified if you know the IDs you will insert upfront (think master-detail). But most ORMs today abstract the problem and implement the two-round-trip (insert master, get ID, insert detail) on your behalf anyway.

Comment: There are certain areas where for regulatory or legal reasons, you cannot have gaps inteh ids. IN this case you cannot use an identity. In most other use cases, the identity is the preferred way to go. BTW causing a permanent performance problem to allow the devs to spend a few minutes less time in devlopement is not a good enough reason. Simpler app code is not the goal in dataabase access, better performance is. There are only two things that trump performance in database code and that is data integrity and data security.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By definition a design like this implies at most one transaction can generate a new sequence for a table (because of the X lock on the record being incremented). In other words, all INSERTs are serialized (no new INSERT can proceed until the first one *commits*). Performance tanks.

IDENTITY on the other hands is capable of generating the sequences concurrently.

If you're stuck with the sequence table you *could* generate the new IDs on a separate transaction, requiring a separate connection to the server, and commit immediately the increment. Or generate in batches (increment +1000) and handle the allocated batch in your app code. The later solution works great at alleviating contention. **But** you loose transactional consistency, the increment occurs on a separate transaction from the INSERT and thus you will see gaps, missing sequences etc. Truth in advertising though: IDENTITY has the same issues (much for the same reasons...)

Comment: I work with a system that uses a table to store/increment sequence numbers. That table is the single biggest bottleneck of the whole system and saying that "performance tanks" when using it is a vast understatement.

Comment: One consideration: volume vs. business requirements. IF you are adding hundreds of rows a second, use identity; if you add no more than a few a minute and there are oddball business rules/requirements underlying the generation of your surrogate keys, you might need to use a procedure.  Certainly sounds like volume and contention is the issue here, however.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: I appreciate your answer very much.  Could you (or anyone else) perhaps elaborate on the specifics of "performance tanks" (perhaps reference how SQL Server might handle this internally)?

Comment: @BryanCrosby: not sure what more to add. For me the explanation I give in first paragraph says everything. But I basically live and breathe SQL Server and I reckon it may not be as clear for some other folk. Let me detail a tad: each xact that needs a new ID **must** increment the value `next_id` for the row with the key `table_name`. As any update, the row will be locked until the xact commits (not until the UPDATE statement finishes, but much longer, until the entire transaction commits). Ergo, only one transaction can generate an ID at any moment.

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Is it reasonable to conclude then that bypassing SQL Server's internal mechanism for identity columns you are adding a lot of unnecessary overhead involved in the row-locking and updating transaction to basically accomplish the exact same thing?

Comment: I would phrase it as such: *`IDENTITY` type uses certain internal optimizations that result in reduced contention when generating IDs. These optimizations are not available for home-grown identities table*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator table to get sequence id's without having the problem of lock contention

-- the shadow table

```
create table dummy_id (
  id int identity not null,
  dummy int not null
)
```

-- proc showing usage

```
create proc dummy_id_gen(@newid int output) as
begin

begin tran
insert dbo.dummy_id (dummy) values (0)
select @newid = scope_identity()
rollback tran

end
```

-- calling the proc to test it

```
declare @newid int
exec dummy_id_gen @newid = @newid output
select @newid as newid
```

This still has the problem of only 1 row at time for the generated ids